# Nim: work with read-only memory mapped files

Tags: nim-lang, memmap

I've only just started with Nim, hence it possibly is a simple question. We need to do many lookups into data that are stored in a file. Some of these files are too large to load into memory, hence the mmapped approach. I'm able to mmap the file by means of memfiles and either have a pointer or MemSlice at my hand. The file and the memory region are read-only, and hence have a fixed size. I was hoping that I'm able to access the data as immutable fixed size byte and char arrays *without* copying them, leveraging all the existing functionalities available to seqs, arrays, strings etc..  All the MemSlice / string methods copy the data, which is fair, but not what I want (and in my use case don't need).

I understand array, strings etc. types have a pointer to the data and a len field. But couldn't find a way to create them with a pointer and len. I assume it has something to do with ownership and refs to mem that may outlive my slice.

```
   let mm = memfiles.open(...)
   let myImmutableFixesSizeArr = ?? # cast[ptr array[fsize, char]](mm.mem) doesn't compile as fsize needs to be const. Neither could I find something like let x: [char] = array_from(mm.mem, fsize)
   let myImmutableFixedSizeString = mm[20, 30].to_fixed_size_immutable_string  # Create something that is string like so that I can use all the existing string methods.
```

UPDATE: I did find https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/4680#29226 which explains how to use OpenArray, but OpenArray is only allowed as function argument, and you - if I'm not mistaken - it is doesn't behave like a normal array.

Thanks for your help

Comment: what sort of processing do you need to do on these strings? are they null-terminated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to convert a raw char array in memory (`ptr UncheckedArray[char]`) to a `string` without copying, only to an `openArray[char]` (or `cstring`)

So it won't be possible to use procs that expect a `string`, only those that accept `openArray[T]` or `openArray[char]`
Happily an `openArray[T]` behaves exactly like a `seq[T]` when sent to a proc.

(`{.experimental:"views".}` does let you assign an openArray[T] to a local variable, but it's not anywhere near ready for production)

---

you can use the `memSlices` iterator to loop over delimited chunks in a memFile without copying:

```py
import memfiles

template toOpenArray(ms: MemSlice, T: typedesc = byte): openArray[T] =
  ##template because openArray isn't a valid return type yet
  toOpenArray(cast[ptr UncheckedArray[T]](ms.data),0,(ms.size div sizeof(T))-1)

func process(slice:openArray[char]) =
  ## your code here but e.g.
  ## count number of A's  
  var nA: int
  for ch in slice.items:
    if ch == 'A': inc nA
  debugEcho nA


let mm = memfiles.open("file.txt")
for slice in mm.memSlices:
  process slice.toOpenArray(char)
```

---

Or, to work with some char array represented in the middle of the file, you can use pointer arithmetic.

```py
import memfiles

template extractImpl(typ,pntr,offset) =
  cast[typ](cast[ByteAddress](pntr)+offset)

template checkFileLen(memfile,len,offset) =
  if offset + len > memfile.size:
    raise newException(IndexDefect,"file too short")

func extract*(mm: MemFile,T:typedesc, offset:Natural): ptr T =
  checkFileLen(mm,T,offset)
  result = extractImpl(ptr T,mm.mem,offset)
func extract*[U](mm: MemFile,T: typedesc[ptr U], offset: Natural): T = 
  extractImpl(T,mm.mem,offset)

let mm = memfiles.open("file.txt")

#to extract a compile-time known length string:
let mystring_offset = 3
const mystring_len = 10

type MyStringT = array[mystring_len,char]

let myString:ptr MyStringT = mm.extract(MyStringT,mystring_offset)
process myString[]

#to extract a dynamic length string:
let size_offset = 14
let string_offset = 18

let sz:ptr int32 = mm.extract(int32,size_offset)
let str:ptr UncheckedArray[char] = mm.extract(ptr UncheckedArray[char], string_offset)

checkFileLen(mm,sz[],string_offset)
process str.toOpenArray(0,sz[]-1)
```

Comment: Thanks, for the confirmation and the examples. Since not many of the typical String methods are available on OpenArray, I assume I have to create or copy&paste the ones I need for my app`?

Comment: According to a previous me, just copy/pasting works: https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/6968#43685 and do try --gc:arc as well